# How to shuffle specific set of elements in a list?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, shuffle

I have created an `ArrayList<MyObjects>`. `MyObject` has an attribute `priority`, and implements the comparable method, which I have overriden.

I want to:

Sort `ArrayList<MyObjects>` based on the `priority` attribute. I've done that with:

```
Collections.sort(ArrayList<MyObjects>)
```

BUT, after the sorting, I want to randomly shuffle (only) the elements that have the same `priority`, keeping the general order of the priority.

---

#### Example:

```
ArrayList <myObject> objectList = new ArrayList <MyObject>();

objectList = {object1, object2, object3, object4,
             object5, object6, object7, object8, object9}

 Collections.sort(objectList)
```

myObject has a `compareTo()` method that compares the `priority` of two myObject.

Supose that, after the sorting, the order of the objects is:

```
object7
object8
object4
object5
object1 // priority = 2
object2 // priority = 2
object3 // priority = 2
object9
object8
```

`object1`, `object2`, and `object3` all have the same priority.

How could I shuffle them without affecting the other objects?

That is, have a list:

```
object7
object8
object4
object5

objectx // priority = 2
objecty // priority = 2
objectz // priority = 2
// where {x, y, z} are randomly selected from {1, 2, 3}

object9
object8
```

I thought of doing a random assignment in the `compareTo()` method when it has an equality.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyObject otherObject) {
    int comparison;

    if (this.priority < otherObject.priority) {comparison = +1;}
    else if (this.priority > otherObject.priority) {comparison = -1;}

    else {
        Random generator = new Random();
        comparison = generator.nextInt( 3 ) - 1;            
    }

    return comparison;
```

But I suppose that when I call the `Collections.sort(ArrayList<MyObjects>)` the randomness will not hold.

---

Should I create my own sorting algorithm?

Or a shuffling algorithm?

Or does there already exists one algorithm that shuffles a specific set of elements in a list?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shuffle the list *before* you sort it. `Collections.sort` is guaranteed to be a stable sort, so equal elements will be in the same order that they were in the unsorted collection... you just need to make sure that that order is a suitably random one. [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) is the simplest way of doing this:

```
Collections.shuffle(objectList);
Collections.sort(objectList);
```

Comment: Probably a good answer for the problem, but this solution inherently shuffles around lots of elements that don't really have to be (i.e. they have unique priorities.) Is there any fix to that?

Comment: @Michael: I'd expect the shuffle to be O(N), and trying to find all the "groups" of equal-priority elements would be O(N) too... so basically, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: Good point; the other solutions would end up with the same complexity. The docs do state a [linear run time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Comment: Even if this solution is technically correct, it suffers from one problem (which I think is important enough to comment about): the business requirement has been solved _implicitly_ and not _explicitly_. What this means is that the person reading/maintaining the code needs to know that a) `MyObject`'s natural sort order is based on priority and b) `Collections.sort()` uses a stable sort algorithm. Unless you carefully document this informaiton, there is a risk that a bug is introduced when e.g. someone decides that it's a good idea to sort the list with QuickSort instead.

Comment: @Mick: I'd certainly expect the class to be documented in terms of its sort order. I'd then just add a comment explaining the use of shuffle and it relying on the ordering being stable. I think it's the simplest solution in terms of the code involved.

Comment: My point was exactly that if the priority-partition was explicit, such comments wouldn't be needed as the code would be self-documenting. It would also make it unnecessary for `MyObject` to implement `Comparable`. But I guess opinions differ..

Comment: @MickMnemonic: Well your option assumes that the OP *wants* a map. It sounds like what they really want is a list in priority order, with objects of equal priority randomly ordered - that's what's described.

Answer (score 1):

You could partition your data into a `TreeMap<Priority, List<MyObject>>` which would map your distinct priorities into sublists of `MyObject`s having the same priority.

With this data structure, you can shuffle these sublists as you wish and iterating over all elements is also trivial (`TreeMap` keeps sublists in priority order).